# Improved a code to work once (no need to repeat)

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming, formatting

If I have the matrix W size `(4 x 4)`

```
W = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}]
```

> $W=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}
>  & a_{3,4} \\  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\ \end{array}
>  \right)$

I use this code

```
With[{inds = DeleteCases[Range@Length@W, 2]}, 
 Table[W[[i, j]] + If[i != j, 1, 0] W[[i, 2]] W[[2, j]], {i, 
   inds}, {j, inds}]]
% // MatrixForm
```

> > $F=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a_{1,1} & a_{1,3}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3} &  a_{1,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,4} \\  a_{3,1}+a_{2,1} a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & 
> >  a_{2,4} a_{3,2}+a_{3,4} \\  a_{4,1}+a_{2,1} a_{4,2} & a_{2,3} 
> >  a_{4,2}+a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\ \end{array} \right)$

I need to repeat this code again to get a 2x2 matrix

```
With[{inds = DeleteCases[Range@Length@F, 2]}, 
 Table[F[[i, j]] + If[i != j, 1, 0] F[[i, 2]] F[[2, j]], {i, 
   inds}, {j, inds}]]
% // MatrixForm
```

> $\scriptsize D=\left( \begin{array}{cc}a_{1,1} &
> a_{1,4}+a_{1,2}a_{2,4}+\left(a_{1,3}+a_{1,2}a_{2,3}\right)\left(a_{2,4}a_{3,2}+a_{3,4}\right)\\ 
> a_{4,1}+a_{2,1}a_{4,2}+\left(a_{3,1}+a_{2,1}a_{3,2}\right)\left(a_{2,3}a_{4,2}+a_{4,3}\right) & a_{4,4} \\  \end{array} \right)$

then apply

```
mi = Expand[Part[D, 1, 2]]
```

> $a_{1,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,4}+a_{1,3} a_{2,4} a_{3,2}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3}a_{2,4}a_{3,2}+a_{1,3} a_{3,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3} a_{3,4}$

Is there a way to write this code in the form of a program executed once without the need to repeat to make in general.

Such as matrix 5x5 we need redundancy 3 times to get 2x2 and the application of the condition

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[m_, r_] :=  Module[{inds = DeleteCases[Range @ Length @ m, r]}, 
   Table[m[[i, j]] + If[i != j, 1, 0] m[[i, r]] m[[r, j]], {i, inds}, {j, inds}]]

f[W, 2] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,3}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3} & a_{1,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1}+a_{2,1} a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{2,4} a_{3,2}+a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1}+a_{2,1} a_{4,2} & a_{2,3} a_{4,2}+a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Nest[f[#, 2] &, W, 2] // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,4}+\left(a_{1,3}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3}\right) \left(a_{2,4} a_{3,2}+a_{3,4}\right) \\
>  a_{4,1}+a_{2,1} a_{4,2}+\left(a_{3,1}+a_{2,1} a_{3,2}\right) \left(a_{2,3} a_{4,2}+a_{4,3}\right) & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: For  `W = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {5, 5}]` I need to repeat three times

Comment: @Emad, use `Nest[f[#, 2] &, W, 3]`

Comment: I put
  `W = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {n = 5, n = 5}]` .The condition is `Nest[f[#, 2] &, W, n - 2]`  to be in general

Comment: How to apply this condition ** mi = Expand[Part[qq, 1, 2]] **with your answer in general

Comment: @Emad, if `qq` is defined as `qq =Nest[f[#, 2] &, W, n - 2]`, just use `mi = Expand[Part[qq, 1, 2]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
func = ExpandAll[Drop[#, {2, 2}, {2, 2}] + ReplacePart[Outer[Times, #, #2] & @@
                 Drop[{#[[All, 2]], #[[2]]}, None, {2, 2}], {a_, a_} -> 0]] &;
Nest[func, W, 2] // MatrixForm
```

> $\scriptsize \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,4}+a_{1,3} a_{2,4} a_{3,2}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3} a_{2,4} a_{3,2}+a_{1,3} a_{3,4}+a_{1,2} a_{2,3} a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1}+a_{2,1} a_{4,2}+a_{2,3} a_{3,1} a_{4,2}+a_{2,1} a_{2,3} a_{3,2} a_{4,2}+a_{3,1} a_{4,3}+a_{2,1} a_{3,2} a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$